# From scop point, __builtin_prefetch(add,0,0)/rte_prefetch0 is it relevant to call from parent or must be call from same function?

Tags: c++, c, prefetch

For example:

```
int add[512];
int cp[512];
inline void PrefetchBuf(const char *pBuf, RU32 nSize)
{
    for (RU32 nPos=0; nPos < nSize; nPos += 64/*chache line size*/)
    {
        __builtin_prefetch(pBuf + nPos,0,0)/rte_prefetch0(pBuf + nPos);
    }
}
int x()
{
    PrefetchBuf(add,512);//can I?
    do somthing(not heavy)
    y();
    return 0;
}

int y()
{
    PrefetchBuf(add,512); // or must from same func?
    memcpy(cp, add, 512)
    return 0;
}
```

From scop point, Is it relevent to call PrefetchBuf from x or I must call it from y?
If not, rte_prefetch**1** can be called from parent?

Comment: why do you think it matters?

Comment: The question came from this. https://www.quora.com/What-happens-when-a-function-is-called-in-C++
My concern can be not related and can come from miss understanding.

Comment: so... why do you think it matters?

Comment: Every function call adds more to the cache, so if the cache is full, it can cause the function stack or the requested peatch data to drop to lower cache level(from L1 to L2)? It theoretical question.

Comment: The cache is big enough to hold your function call and 512 bytes of data and more.